# VS Code - форматирование CSS - перенос классов на другую строку

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, scss, форматирование, форматирование-кода

Дано:

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

При форматировании (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>),происходит перенос h2 на новую строку.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы h2 не переносило на новую строку? Где эта настройка?

Использую как стандартный форматтер так и Prettier.

Comment: Настройки - Расширения -Возможности языка CSS - CSS - Разделить селекторы новой строкой. Либо в JSON "css.format.newlineBetweenSelectors": false

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, какое расширение используете для форматтера css

Comment: Использую Prettier, но стандартный тоже пойдет.

Comment: @АндрейМиронов ,  совет подошёл.
Если кто ещё про Prettier подскажет, будет замечательно.

Comment: @АндрейМиронов , оформите как ответ, помечу решенным.